# Окончание «-ее» в дореформенной орфографии

Tags: орфография, окончания, старая-орфография, старая-грамматика

Всегда ли пишется окончание «-ее» с ятью (-ѣе)? Пример: «Это лучшѣе, что было за сегодня!», «Ранѣе утро было за окном». В Википедии не написано, что странно.

Comment: Утро было ранѣе?

Comment: 1. Раннояденiе — яденiе по утру, невоздержанность въ пищѣ. 2. За окномъ.